# Enabling Ethernet X3530 M4

Tags: ethernet, interface, ibm-xseries

I have IBM X3530 M4, and it appears to have 4 ethernet ports, but under Ubuntu just 2 ethernet ports are enabled.  How can I enable the other two ethernet ports?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [server specifications](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/x/hardware/rack/x3530m4/specs.html), the second pair of ethernet interfaces are [FoD (Feature on Demand)](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4895.html).  You must buy a license to enable use of these ports.